# computing the expectation using sampling

Tags: probability, statistics, machine-learning

I was reading the gradient temporal difference learning version 2(GTD2) from rich Sutton's book page-246. At some point, he expressed the whole expectation using a single sample from the environment. But how a single sample can represent the whole expectation. I marked this point in this image:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5MDM.png)

Comment: Indeed, using just one sample gives an approximation for the expected value. The equality sign should be replaced by an approximation sign.

Comment: can you add some explanation, please?

Comment: By the Law of Large Numbers, the Expected Value can be approximated by the mean of some finite number of samples. An extreme case of this is to approximate the expected value by a single sample.

Comment: So, if we approximate the expected value by a single sample, then we have to take average of those samples. But here we are not taking any average, we just summing those samples as time passes by.